# Average of dataframes values in a list by name

Tags: r, list, nested

I have a question related to R and nested lists.
Let's assume I have a nested list with this structure:

```
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

simul<-list(
  "Q"=tibble(
    months = seq(1,12,by=1),
    run1 = runif(12),
    run2 = runif(12),
    run3= runif(12)),
  "ET1"=tibble(
    months = seq(1,12,by=1),
    run1 = runif(12),
    run2 = runif(12),
    run3= runif(12)),
  "ET2"=tibble(
    months = seq(1,12,by=1),
    run1 = runif(12),
    run2 = runif(12),
    run3= runif(12)),
  "ET3"=tibble(
    months = seq(1,12,by=1),
    run1 = runif(12),
    run2 = runif(12),
    run3= runif(12))
  )
```

I am trying to obtain some averages by variables ("ET") and by run, thus maintaining the lower-level list structure. The variables are grouped by their starting characters, and vary by the number at the end.

So far I solved my problem in this way, however, I was wondering if you could please suggest to me a better way, which I can apply easily to a larger list, with more "variables" and "runs".

```
nested_avg <-list("Q"=simul["Q"],
                  "ET"=tibble(months = simul$ET1$months,
                              run1=rowMeans(do.call(cbind, simul[c("ET1","ET2","ET3")]%>% map(2))),
                              run2=rowMeans(do.call(cbind, simul[c("ET1","ET2","ET3")]%>% map(3))),
                              run3=rowMeans(do.call(cbind, simul[c("ET1","ET2","ET3")]%>% map(4)))
                  ))
```

Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: What are the patterns in the variable names? Can we assume that if they end with a number, that the underlying pattern is everything but the last character?

Comment: Yes, I always have the same string followed by a number (i.e., ET1,ET2, ..., ETn and run1, run2,...,run100)

Comment: And you just want to take the average of all the dataframes starting with that prefix, correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some `enframe` then `deframe` with grouping does the trick:

```r
simul %>%
  setNames(str_remove_all(names(.), "\\d")) %>%
  enframe() %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(value = list(as_tibble(Reduce("+", value) / n()))) %>%
  deframe()
```

Note that the `as_tibble` is necessary because `Reduce` automatically converts to matrix.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you. Is there also a way also to exclude one of the columns from the average /Reduce function? For example, if the column "months" of the Tibble is a class date. the summarise function causes an error  (binary + is not defined for "Date" objects)

Comment: Just add another pipe and `lapply(function(x) select(x, -(where(lubridate::is.Date) & matches("months"))))`. The matrix might undo the classes, so consider applying that step before `setNames`.

Answer (score 2):

Looping and `Map`ping (not `purrr::map`, `base::Map` in this instance):

```
vars <- startsWith(names(simul), "ET")
out <- list(
    "Q" = simul["Q"],
    "ET" = as_tibble(do.call(Map, c(\(...) rowMeans(cbind(...)), simul[vars])))
)

identical(out, nested_avg)
#[1] TRUE
```

And an alternative method flattening everything to an array:

```
out <- list(
  "Q" = simul["Q"],
  "ET" = as_tibble(apply(sapply(simul[vars], as.matrix, simplify="array"), 1:2, mean))
)

identical(out, nested_avg)
#[1] TRUE
```